# Refer to the post instead of main site page after tapping on the site icon on the Feed page in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The Feed page of the iOS app contains replies, interesting and hot questions etc:

> [image: feed]

I noticed that tapping on the site icon refers to the “main page” of the site, i.e. to the list of all questions. But only tapping on post title or text below opens post instead.

> [image: item]

It’s slightly confusing because when I tap on the item in the Feed page I expect referring to the post even if I did tap on the icon.

The fact that site “main page” doesn’t contain back button aggravates the situation, i.e. I need to choose Feed item in the main app menu to return to the Feed page. If you open post then back button exists in the left top corner.

So my request is to refer to the post even if you tap on the site icon for the feed’s item.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)